# python - profile the memory cost of all imports?

Tags: python, memory, profiling

I'm not quite sure if this is possible or not...

I have a large Python application that grows to a large memory size.  I am hoping to track the process growth by `import` statement to minimize that if possible.

The closest that I've found is the line profiling feature of `memory_profiler`.  That will only profile the memory of a "toplevel" `import` statement though - and I want a breakdown of all the subordinate imports.  I haven't found any profiler that can track memory size to the import statement.

This is a concern not just to optimize our own code, but because a recent audit showed some PyPi modules enabling 3rd party framework support by simply dropping the `import` statement in a try/except block.

for example, one library did this:

```
try:
    import bottle
    # declare bottle support here
except:
    pass
```

While my app is deployed in a virtualenv, there are several other sibling services that are part of the deployment and run in the same virtualenv... one of which uses `bottle`.

This "pattern" is used in a handful of libraries I use, and the overhead of unwanted/unneeded modules is at decent amount of this application's memory imprint (based on manually isolating and measuring them). I would like to figure out which libraries to prioritize patching and which ones I can safely ignore.

Comment: How about using `sys.getsizeof`? E.g. `import pandas; print(getsizeof(pandas))`

Comment: that doesn't work on modules.  `pympler` has an `asizeof` function that seems to work though.  I ended up overriding the import statement though, as that gave me an ordering of imports (which makes it somewhat easier to track down).

Answer (score 1):

After not having much luck, I had a wacky idea and it somewhat works.

I overrode the `import` statement to calculate the current memory of a given process before and after every import.  I don't think this covers every import situation, but it's a good start.  I simply printed this, then copy/pasted it onto a file, and then did some quick preprocessing  to turn it into a csv that tracks the index and percent growth/total of each call.  that's enough for my current needs.

```
import os
import psutil
import __builtin__
this_process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
realimport = __builtin__.__import__
def myimp(name, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        _mem_start = this_process.get_memory_info()[0]
        r = realimport(name, *args, **kwargs)
        _mem_finish = this_process.get_memory_info()[0]
        _mem_growth = _mem_finish - _mem_start
        print "import|%s,%s,%s,%s" % (name, _mem_growth, _mem_start, _mem_finish)
        return r
    except:
        raise
__builtin__.__import__ = myimp
```

There are better ways to do the above, and I still hope there are better ways to profile an app like this.  For now, I've got a working solution.